# Combining Attributed Strings

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsattributedstring

As an example, say I had an array of 10 `NSAttributedStrings`, what is the best method for combining them all into one string? I know of the `appendAttributedString` method, but this only allows for one to be combined at a time, meaning a loop is needed.
Or is there any need to combine them if theyre just going into a textview - just have a loop to add them to that view? Im just trying to get my head around how a lot of text in different formats is added to a textview!

Comment: And what's wrong with a loop?

Comment: if all 10s are not an array, what's wrong in using 10 lines to append?

Comment: Nothing if the Strings are in an array, but if theyre defined and named separately then it gets a little difficult? Are loops the way lots of strings are added to a text view? It seems to me ios makes it very difficult to just display text with fairly basic formatting on a page!

Comment: "but if theyre defined and named separately" - and if they're not in an array already, then you made a huge design mistake and you'll need to refactor your code anyway.

Comment: you can create a utility method/class that will serve your purpose, by writing a subclass/category.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya - it just seemed to me that this is alot of code to append the strings - if I had say 30 of them, 30 lines to append seems a bit o.t.t.?

Comment: @Giovanni Again, you should already be using an array if you have 30 strings.

Comment: @H2CO3 I appreciate that they should be in an array, so your saying the way to get basic text from strings into a textview is with a simple string array and a loop into the textview?

Comment: @Giovanni I don't understand that sentence, sorry. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry, ill rephrase. If my array of 10 strings are to be added to a uitextview, they need to be combined at some point. Would this be done in code and then a longer appended string is passed to the view, or would each string be passed to the uitextview individually? Im in the very early stages of ios development so sincere apologies if this is a daft question!

Comment: good way is to pass a longer appended string.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try:

```
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
    NSString *space = @" ";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attSpace = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:space];
    [attSpace addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range];
    [attSpace addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"
                                                                     size:11.f] range:range];

    range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);
    NSMutableAttributedString *att1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string1];
    [att1 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range];
    [att1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"
                                                                       size:11.f] range:range];

    range = NSMakeRange(0, [string2 length]);
    NSMutableAttributedString *att2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string2];
    [att2 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range];
    [att2 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"
                                                                       size:11.f] range:range];

    [att1 appendAttributedString:attSpace];
    [att1 appendAttributedString:att2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll share a kind of complex combination I've made mixing plain, striked and bold text in a resultant attributed string over the title of UIButton.

```
// Monthly button
NSMutableAttributedString *strikedOutPrice = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"6,99"];

[strikedOutPrice setAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @2 } range:NSMakeRange(0, [strikedOutPrice length])];

NSMutableAttributedString *boldPrice = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"4,99"];

[boldPrice setAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] } range:NSMakeRange(0, [boldPrice length])];

NSMutableAttributedString* titleStringMonthly = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@" , [[LocalizationSystem sharedLocalSystem] localizedStringForKey:@"1 Month for" value:@"1 Mes por"], @"6,99", @"4,99"]];

[titleStringMonthly setAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] } range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleStringMonthly length])];

NSString *language = [Utils getAppLanguage];
if([language isEqualToString:@"es"])
{
    [titleStringMonthly replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, 4) withAttributedString:strikedOutPrice];
    [titleStringMonthly replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(15, 4) withAttributedString:boldPrice];
}
else
{
    [titleStringMonthly replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(12, 4) withAttributedString:strikedOutPrice];
    [titleStringMonthly replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(17, 4) withAttributedString:boldPrice];
}

[_oneMonthButton setAttributedTitle:titleStringMonthly forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**I imagine that for this case you could have a couple of dynamic counters that keeps track of the index and length of the next range and make the replacements over a NSMutableAttributedString (like I do with my titleStringMonthly on the example)**

Hope It helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this

```
NSString *attr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", attributedString1, string2, string3];
```

Doing so will result in one `attr` string variable with all 10 of the strings put together, and you could do `[textView setText:attr];` :)

Comment: isnt question about attributed string ?